# Keep having Run time error 53 when opening Microsoft Office 2021

Tags: ms-office

Keep having Run-time error '53' pop up window when opening Microsoft  Office 2021 Word, Power point or Excel. I have reinstalled the Office completely and tried otre different suggested solutions but nothing helped.
It looks like I have to live with this stupid bug for the rest of my life ! Despite there are a few advice how to resolve this bug but nothing help for me.

Run-time error '53':
File not found: /Library/Application Support/Adobe/
MACPDFM/MacPDFM.framework/Versions/A/MacPDFM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems to be answered already over here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407354/100302