# Everytime I start Word or Excel I get a dialogue box: Visual Basic for Applications Run-time error 53

Tags: ms-office

I'm using Mac Office 2021 and OS Monterey on an Apple MacBook Air (M2). Every time I try to open a Word or Excel document I get a dialogue box with the Run-time Error 53 message or the screen freezes on me and I have to force quit the application. Can anyone help me get rid of this extremely annoying issue please?

Comment: Have you reinstalled Office? Is this every document, or just some? What about a new document? Do these documents contain macros?

Comment: Have you read (all) the answers here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407353/how-to-fix-run-time-error-53-every-time-i-open-a-document-in-word-or-a-worksheet

Comment: Yes, no change when I reinstall MS Office. 
It happens with every new Word doc I open regardless of whether it is a previously created Word doc or a new one that I try to set up. There is an Exit button in the dialogue box but when I tap that the box reappears and I have to go through the p[process three times - then the Word doc will open. At other times it just freezes Word and I have to do a forced quit.